# Visual Studio 2010 Windows Forms Designer Problems

Tags: entity-framework-4, windows-forms-designer, ado.net-entity-data-model

Isn't that a crazy error?

I get this when trying to open a form containing some UserControls from another assebly and using Entity Framework and SQL CE on visual studio designer.

Object of type Namespace.T[] cannot be converted to type Namespace.T[]!!!

Call Stack:

at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast) at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr) at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalSetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean doVisibilityCheck, Boolean doCheckConsistency) at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.SerializationSetValue(MemberInfo fi, Object target, Object value) at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteObject(ObjectHolder holder, Boolean bObjectFullyComplete) at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoNewlyRegisteredObjectFixups(ObjectHolder holder) at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.RegisterObject(Object obj, Int64 objectID, SerializationInfo info, Int64 idOfContainingObj, MemberInfo member, Int32[] arrayIndex) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.RegisterObject(Object obj, ParseRecord pr, ParseRecord objectPr, Boolean bIsString) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ParseObjectEnd(ParseRecord pr) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Parse(ParseRecord pr) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run() at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream) at System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GenerateObjectFromDataNodeInfo(DataNodeInfo dataNodeInfo, ITypeResolutionService typeResolver) at System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GetValue(ITypeResolutionService typeResolver) at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseDataNode(XmlTextReader reader, Boolean isMetaData) at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseXml(XmlTextReader reader)

But its the same name type exactly!

The project builds successfully and runs ok!!!

OK i deleted the .resx file of the form and now i get 2 other errors i thought i have passed.

1st is "The specified named connection, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid"

Call Stack:

at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName) at DJPro.Settings.Model.SettingsEntities..ctor() in D:\Visual Studio Projects\DJProAutomation\DJPro.Settings.Model\SettingsSelfTrackModel.Context.cs:line 33 at DJPro.Data.Access.SettingsDataOperations.GetConfiguration() in D:\Visual Studio Projects\DJProAutomation\DJPro.Data.Access\SettingsDataOperations.cs:line 33 at DJPro.Studio.Controls.DeckControl..ctor() in D:\Visual Studio Projects\DJProAutomation\DJPro.Deck.Controls\DeckControl.cs:line 51

2nd is about a control i have on a library saying.

"The variable deckControl1 is either undeclared or was never assigned"

Call Stack:

at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.Error(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String exceptionText, String helpLink) at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression) at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression) at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)

Then restored from a backup the resx file and im going back to the first problem.

So strange errors, everything seems fine in the Entity Data Model libraries and the app.config has all the necessary connection strings. As for the deckControl1 UserControl it seems fine to the library i have created it and opens ok.

I think this gets me crazy enough and stops the development.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, if you use in UserControl constructor code that initializes entity framework context provides problems....even problem can occur while trying to initialize context for data operations in the Load event handler.

Tricky!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a version conflict between the assembly used to generate the ResX and the currently referenced assembly.

Try removing the reference, re-adding it as a project reference, and regenerating the ResX.

Comment: I have deleted from the resx file a property where i use inside the code...and this kinda works, haven't tested yet full, i eill do that if this wont work.